build container image for nodejs app with playright to run on aws lambda
I try to build container image to run on AWS Lambda. Runtime: nodejs, lib: playwright.
According to here, I tried this dockerfile:
# Use the AWS Lambda Node.js 20 base image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20

# Install system dependencies for Playwright
RUN yum -y update && yum install -y \
    libX11 libgbm libnss libatk libatk-bridge libcups libdrm libxkbcommon \
    libXrandr libXcomposite libXdamage libXfixes libcairo pango alsa-lib \
    libdbus-1 libatspi gtk3

# Copy application code
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install application dependencies
RUN npm install

# Download the browsers for Playwright
RUN npx playwright install

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD ["crawler.handler"]


But gives an error like this:
0.232 /bin/sh: line 1: yum: command not found

I tried apt-get also but same. How can I install my dependencies and build my dockerfile?

Something you want to take a look into? https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/17uahqv/comment/k92h67e/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button
